# Trying to upload a file from file explorer using java/selenium

Tags: java, windows, selenium

I am trying to write a java program that uses selenium to perform web actions.   In the case of uploading a video there is a frame where the user clicks that brings up the File Explorer for Windows.   I have not been able to find anything that will help me in getting the focus to the File Explorer to select a file.  There is no "browse" on the page with a textbox for me to just send a filename to.

Here is what the page looks like:
[image: upload_video]

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [Selenide](http://selenide.org/documentation.html) because it has a pre-canned  upload utility that might save you some time/effort.   See the command .uploadFromClasspath in the docs.  One of the project videos/pages shows a little more detail on how to do it.

I've not actually tried it, but if this works for you and you figure it out, please share.

What I have done in the past is to use the "Apache HttpUtils" class to simulate the upload action from my test. All you need is the upload URL, and the HTML page usually provides that. That might also work for you.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the correct files to download Selenide??   Can you post the exact link please??

Comment: @Janet - yes, the download is done by your build system, such as Maven:  http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.codeborne|selenide|3.1.1|jar   If you want to do it the hard way, without a build system, then you can manually download the .jar from there.